# TSLint marks as an error when comparing string with char

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have a snippet that compares a string with a char and TSLint is complaining about everything:

Version 1:

```
checkSomething(myString: string): boolean {
  let myBool = false;
  if (myString === '3') {
    myBool = true;
  }
  return myBool;
}
```

With this code, the comparison is always evaluated to false, since it compares a string with a char (char type doesn't exist in TypeScript)

---

Version 2:

```
checkSomething(myString: string): boolean {
  let myBool = false;
  if (myString == '3') {
    myBool = true;
  }
  return myBool;
}
```

This comparison is evaluated to true when `myString` is set to `"3"`, but TSLint complains about the double-equals: `[tslint] == should be === (triple-equals)`.

---

Version 3:

```
checkSomething(myString: string): boolean {
  let myBool = false;
  if (myString === "3") {
    myBool = true;
  }
  return myBool;
}
```

This comparison is evaluated to true when myString is set to `"3"`, but TSLint complains about the double quotes: `[tslint] " should be ' (quotemark)`.

What should be the correct way to avoid errors in TSLint in this case?

Comment: There is no such thing as `char` in both Javascript and Typescript. Your first version just works and it doesn't evaluate to false if you pass in string "3". Quotes and double quotes are also the same thing in JS. Maybe look up Typescript tutorial before going on, forget C#

Comment: @ritaj sorry, but I did my tests and it's evaluated to false, seems like they are considered as different types.

Comment: No. I don't know how are you doing these tests, but it definitely evaluates to `true` and they are not different types. "3" can not be of any type other than `string` since, again, `char` type does. Not. Exist. [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20checkSomething(myString%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20myBool%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(myString%20%3D%3D%3D%20'3')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myBool%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20return%20myBool%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(checkSomething(%223%22)%20%2B%20%22%2C%20obviously%22)%3B)